# jquery trigger when class doesnt contain 'disabled'

Tags: jquery

Here is my code, which doesn't seem to be working!

```
$('a#welcome').not("[class*='disabled']").click( function() {
```

Trying to trigger the object with ID 'welcome' when class doesn't contain 'disabled' in the class.

Thank

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a#welcome').not('.disabled').click(function(){});
```

Or

```
$('a#welcome:not(.disabled)').click(function(){});
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, if your class is being added/removed dynamically, a normal jQuery selector won't work.

You'll need to bind the event dynamically:

```
$(document).on('click', '#welcome:not(.disabled)', function() {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: just saw this after i posted answer to my own question. you are correct sir.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a#welcome').not(".disabled").click( function() { ...
```

the period `.`, means class, so you don't need to use the `[class=]` selector.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it wasn't working is because class was being changed dynamically.

Have upgraded code to this which works:

```
$(document).on("click", "a#welcome:not(.disabled)", function() {
```